# Nextjs add background image tailwind

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

So, I have this code login.js:

```
function Login() {
return ( 
<div className="bg-deskbg">

</div>
);}
export default Login;
```

and in tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      "pacifico": ['Pacifico', 'cursive'],
      "righteous": ['Righteous', 'cursive'],

    },
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'deskbg' : "url('../public/bg.jpg')",
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I am trying to put the image bg.jpg as a background image but t's not working, what shall I do.

Comment: replace `url('../public/bg.jpg')` with `url(/bg.jpg)'`. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: No, the problem is not the this.

Comment: The best way to determine where comes from the problem is to check from the web console if you can access the image or not. 
Most probably, it is your problem. Maybe it is not it the right folder.
An other thing you can try is to add content in the div, because maybe your image is there but your div is of 0px height...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mr.Baldráni he told me that I have to put a height for it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with icons in header in next, try using this

```js
const getImageUrl = (logo: string): string => {
  return new URL(`/src/assets/logos/${example}`, import.meta.url).toString();
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).